# Matlab, Plot/Graph Changes when the Line Style Changes

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab ver R2017A. When I plot the following code below, I get a sine wave as expected using the default line style.

```
x = linspace(0,10);
h1 = sin(x);
plot([x,h1],'--')
legend('Location','southwest')
```

However, when I add a different line style, the plot goes all wonky. From a sine wave, it changes to some half triangular wave followed by very small sine waves, with of course using a dashed line style.

```
x = linspace(0,10);
h1 = sin(x);
plot([x,h1],'--')
legend('Location','southwest')
```

I then tried the following, but now the plot/graph completely disappeared from the figure. All I see are the X and Y axes:

```
plot(x,h1,"LineStyle",'--');
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh forget it. I fixed the issue. I needed to remove the square brackets. I assumed the R2022 syntax was the same as documented in R2017A. By default, a search on google will bring you to the latest version of the documentation. I decided to search R2017A and there it was; no square brackets. The latest Matlab documentation would normally mention changes to the syntax from previous version, but in this case it did not.

Comment: Not sure what documentation you've been reading, but `plot([x,h1])` is not documented for R2022a, and does not produce a plot of `h1` vs `x`. It never has and never will. `[x,h1]` is a vector in your case, so it will plot the concatenation of those two shapes. If the two variables were column vectors indeed, such as `[x',h1']`, then you'd see the two shapes plotted individually, in different colors. In both cases, the x axis is just the indices into the data.

Comment: I was looking at this webpage, at the section Line Styles. I guess it threw me off ... https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/specify-line-and-marker-appearance-in-plots.html. plot([0 1 2 3],'--') The portion that is plotted is in square brackets.